# how to add an icon to the title bar in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, icons, gmail, title

when getting a message on gmail, a speaker icon appears and fades away after a seconds, how did they do it?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: They play a sound. icon shows up when a tab has sound.

Comment: http://chrome.blogspot.com/2014/01/everyone-can-now-track-down-noisy-tabs.html

Answer (score 1):

That comes from the browser, not the site.
To reproduce it, just have your website make a sound.